# Flask throws ascii character error in WSGI server but not in debug local server?

Tags: python, flask

The Flask server is working perfectly fine on local debug mode on my Mac OS, but it's throwing ASCII character encoding error on AWS Ubuntu 18.04 server.

What I want to do is submit a HTML form to the server and process the contents in it. On the local debug mode, python application.py receives 'word': '愿意', but on the AWS server it receives 'word': '\xe6\x84\xbf\xe6\x84\x8f'

I spent almost 2 days searching for the problem. At first I thought the server on AWS was using python 2.7 instead of 3.6, but it turns out there wasn't any problem with python.

Then, I thought the HTML template was sending the form input in an encoded format, but apparently HTML file has header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

After that, I thought the system encoding was different and changed .conf file to: WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp lang='en_US.utf8' locale='en_US.utf8'

But still no luck. Has anyone has encountered a similar problem before?

application.py

```
@app.route('/generate',methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def generate():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        result = request.form
        result = dict(result)

        print(request.form)
        print(result)

        download_path = 'data/%s/%s' % (result['lang'], result['word'])
        if not os.path.isdir(download_path):
            os.mkdir(download_path)
```

index.html

```
<form action="/generate" method = "POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <p><input type="text" name="word"></p>
    <p><input type="text" name="lang"></p>
</form>
```

the error I'm getting is:

```
[Sat Dec 28 08:08:59.605358 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21499:tid 139977571268352] [remote 45.56.197.253:64616]   File "/var/www/html/FlaskApp/application.py", line 114, in generate
[Sat Dec 28 08:08:59.605362 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21499:tid 139977571268352] [remote 45.56.197.253:64616]     os.mkdir(download_path)
[Sat Dec 28 08:08:59.605367 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 21499:tid 139977571268352] [remote 45.56.197.253:64616] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data/Chinese/\xe6\x84\xbf\xe6\x84\x8f_20191228'
```

Comment: The problem isn't the file name, it's that at least one of the parent directories does not exist.

Comment: Thank you so much. I thought it couldn't find the file due to the encoding issues, because the parent directories actually exist. But apparently I must have written the full directory. Btw it was throwing ASCII errors before I add the ```WSGIDaemonProcess FlaskApp lang='en_US.utf8' locale='en_US.utf8' ```